# how to go back to parent activity on pressing back button from last child activity when using activity group?

Tags: android, tabs, back, activitygroup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to navigate from activity in one activity group to another activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435630/how-to-navigate-from-activity-in-one-activity-group-to-another-activity-in-andro)

In my application I have tabs, Inside tab i have used Activity Group , It contain  6 activities , I want to go back to First  activity ( parent ) on pressing back button ( phone back button ) from last child activity ?   .....Please help me with some examples